# GitServer 'git add ' Permission denied, Can not change branch

Tags: windows, git, apache

When I have tried to

```
git add var/log/errorApache.log
```

on a windows machine I get the following error:

```
Permission denied
```

Comment: It was on a windows machine..

Comment: git add from where? Are you sure that's the path of apache logs? why are you adding a log file to git?

Comment: It is happening most probably because the ownser of that file is `www-data`, and your user can't access that file.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to change branch, then it says can not change branch because of this file. then tried to add in git rep.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Problem resolved, It was Apache error log location. that's why it was not getting the permission to access the file.Steps to resolve the issue 1. Stop Apache, 2. Delete the file. 3. Added this file in gitignore 4. restart Apache. and its working fine. No permission issue, and changing branches. Thanks a lot for your help mu.

Comment: Just to clarify, it was in magneto project, location is "C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\learning2\var\log\errorApache.log", so it s not Linux '/var' folder.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was the name of the log file that was different - I have seen `var/log/system.log`, but didn't recall `errorApache.log` was a default log file.

Comment: I have posted the discussion as an answer, have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening most probably because the owner of that file is `www-data` (i.e., `apache`), and your user can't access that file.

As OP mentions in comments, following steps worked for him:

1. Stop `Apache`
2. Delete the file
3. Added this file in `.gitignore`
4. restart `Apache`.